# How to get public Google Spreadsheet data using Google Spreadsheet API Java library without authentication

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-authentication

-what I want to do

I would like to get data from Google Spreadsheet using Google Spreadsheet API Java library without authentication. 
The Google Spreadsheet is published with public.
I would like to use the following method:
com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.CustomElementCollection

-Issue

CustomElementCollection return collect data with authentication.
But CustomElementCollection return null without authentication.

As listEntry.getPlainTextContent() shows data, so I think I should be able to get the data in any ways.

-Source code attached

With authentication: Auth.java

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.ListQuery;
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.CustomElementCollection;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.ListEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.ListFeed;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.WorksheetEntry;

public class Auth {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String applicationName = "AppName";
        String user = args[0];
        String pass = args[1];
        String key = args[2];
        String query = args[3];

        SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService(applicationName);
        service.setUserCredentials(user, pass); //set client auth 

        URL entryUrl = new URL("http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/" + key);
        SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheetEntry = service.getEntry(entryUrl, SpreadsheetEntry.class);
        WorksheetEntry worksheetEntry = spreadsheetEntry.getDefaultWorksheet();

        ListQuery listQuery = new ListQuery(worksheetEntry.getListFeedUrl());
        listQuery.setSpreadsheetQuery( query );

        ListFeed listFeed = service.query(listQuery, ListFeed.class);
        List<ListEntry> list = listFeed.getEntries();
        for( ListEntry listEntry : list )
        {
            System.out.println( "content=[" + listEntry.getPlainTextContent() + "]");
            CustomElementCollection elements = listEntry.getCustomElements();
            System.out.println(
                    " name=" + elements.getValue("name") + 
                    " age="  + elements.getValue("age") );
        }
    }
}
```

Without authentication: NoAuth.java

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.FeedURLFactory;
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.ListQuery;
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.CustomElementCollection;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.ListEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.ListFeed;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.WorksheetEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.WorksheetFeed;

public class NoAuth {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String applicationName = "AppName";
        String key = args[0];
        String query = args[1];

        SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService(applicationName);

        URL url = FeedURLFactory.getDefault().getWorksheetFeedUrl(key, "public", "basic");

        WorksheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(url, WorksheetFeed.class);
        List<WorksheetEntry> worksheetList = feed.getEntries();
        WorksheetEntry worksheetEntry = worksheetList.get(0);

        ListQuery listQuery = new ListQuery(worksheetEntry.getListFeedUrl());
        listQuery.setSpreadsheetQuery( query );

        ListFeed listFeed = service.query( listQuery, ListFeed.class );
        List<ListEntry> list = listFeed.getEntries();
        for( ListEntry listEntry : list )
        {
            System.out.println( "content=[" + listEntry.getPlainTextContent() + "]");
            CustomElementCollection elements = listEntry.getCustomElements();
            System.out.println(
                    " name=" + elements.getValue("name") + 
                    " age="  + elements.getValue("age") );
        }
    }
}
```

Google Spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ajawooo6A9OldHV0VHYzVVhTZlB6SHRjbGc5MG1CakE&output=html

-Result

Without authentication

content=[age: 23]
 　　　name=null age=null

With authentication

content=[age: 23]
 　　　name=Taro age=23

Please let me know the useful information to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why it works like that, but when you don't access request with credentials, you are not able to retrieve cells via:

```
CustomElementCollection elements = listEntry.getCustomElements();
System.out.println(" name=" + elements.getValue("name") + " age="  + elements.getValue("age") );
```

I've tested it and I have found only this way to retrieve data:

```
List<ListEntry> list = listFeed.getEntries();
for (ListEntry row : list) {
    System.out.println(row.getTitle().getPlainText() + "\t"
            + row.getPlainTextContent());
}
```

It prints:

```
Taro    age: 23
Hanako  age: 16
```

As you see, you should parse text and retrieve age from raw `String`.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort! I will try.

Comment: Please take a look at euclio's answer. It explains why the codes in the question do not work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that you are using the `"basic"` projection for your spreadsheet. If you use the `"values"` projection, everything should work as expected.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: What do you mean? The accepted answer certainly doesn't answer the question. Switching from the basic projection to the values projection fixes the problem.

Comment: I think this should be the right answer. I have tested it. The accepted answer is sort of working, but does not accomplish what the original question really wants.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering about this as well. I looked at the feed coming in (just paste the URL to the sheet into Chrome), and it seems like there is no XML markup, and are all coming in under the <content> tag. So it makes sense that the parser is lumping it all into the text content of the BaseEntry (instead of making a ListEntry).